# Can I map user available information to a PSID?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook messenger bot attached to my company page. When a user talks to it I get a JSON payload sent to the webhook I provide that contains the sender.id (PSID I believe) that lets me post back to a user. They don't talk to us in any other way and they don't authenticate so this seems to be the only info I have.

In order to get answers for the user we contact other systems, possibly logging information they send us. For privacy reasons we want to allow a user to contact our support and request that any communication they had with the bot be deleted.

My fear is that the user will not know their PSID (is there a way they can easily get it?)

If not, is there anyway I could map the PSID to something that uniquely identifies the user that a nontechnical user could be expected to get? (The id that appears on their profile page, their e-mail, etc)

I know I can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile to get some nonunique info about a user (their name, etc but I couldn't find a unique id here) 
and I know I can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching to map to an ASID but that doesn't seem to help me either (we don't have any contact point besides our messenger bot)

My fear is that the user will have no way to obtain the PSID and that we'll have no way to programmatically convert PSID to something that uniquely identifies a user but I was wondering if anyone has solved this problem.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why handle that via support in the first place ... why not have them send a specific message like `delete account` to your bot, maybe an additional confirmation after that ... and then purge them from your system?

Comment: that's a possibility and if there is no other solution we might go that route. But we typically purge at the db level based on a unique id. I'm curious if PSID can be mapped to any type of information a user might be able to reasonably obtain.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the intent of PSID and it is to prevent this very thing.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of the PSID is to give you something that allows you to identify the user only in the context of the specific page they are interacting with. PSID/ASID Matching would be one way to make the connection to the Graph API user object, Account Linking another one (you would simply send the user to a website where your app asks them log in to then.)

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.  I believe I understand the account linking option.  For the PSID/ASID matching, would that help here? I don't know much about ASID but it sounded like it would be another id that the user might have trouble obtaining and providing to me?

Comment: The app-scoped user id is the id your normal Facebook app sees, when the user logs in to it via normal Facebook login - not a thing the user could otherwise “see” anywhere either.